# how I can pass messages from one component to page

Tags: javascript, next.js

so I have next.js project and there I got stuck, so I will explain my situation with code:

I have layout.tsx in app directory

```js
    export default async function RootLayout({
      children,
    }: Readonly<{
      children: React.ReactNode;
    }>) {
      const { user } = await getServerSession();
    
      return (
        <body className="h-full w-full bg-[#171717] text-white flex items-start justify-center">
          <DashboardDisplay userId={user.id}>{children}</DashboardDisplay>
        </body>
      );
    }
```

there is DashboardDisplay:

```js
    const DashboardDisplay = ({ children, userId }: any) => {
      const { status, toggle, toggleBySize } = useToggle();
    
      const toggleNavigation = status ? "md:!w-[260px]" : "!w-0";
    
      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", (x) => toggleBySize(window.innerWidth));
    
        return () =>
          window.removeEventListener("resize", () =>
            toggleBySize(window.innerWidth)
          );
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <>
          <header
            className={`${toggleNavigation} w-full max-w-lg md:max-w-sm h-full overflow-auto z-50 left-0 absolute md:relative`}
          >
            <Navigation onBurger={toggle} />
          </header>
          <main className="flex-1 h-full box-border relative">
            <MobileNavigation className="absolute top-0" />
            <ToggleButton
              onClick={toggle}
              status={status}
              className="absolute left-0 top-[45%] hidden md:block z-40"
            />
    
            <ChatDisplay userId={userId}>{children}</ChatDisplay>
          </main>
        </>
      );
    };
```

so chatDisplay is a layout of `"/dashboard"` and `"/chat/:chatId"` pages:

```js
    const ChatDisplay = ({ messagesData, userId, children }: any) => {
      const [messages, setMessages] = useState(messagesData);
    
      const router = useParams();
    
      return (
        <div className="w-full h-full relative flex flex-col">
          <main className="w-full overflow-auto">
            <MobileNavigation className="sticky top-0 z-40" />
          </main>
          <div className="flex-1">{children}</div>
          <footer className="text-base w-full py-3 px-4 md:px-0 flex flex-col gap-2 bg-[#171717] max-w-3xl m-auto">
            <ChatFooter
              chatId={router.chatId as string}
              userId={userId}
              setAiMessage={setMessages}
              warningInfo="ChatGPT can make mistakes. Consider checking important information."
            />
          </footer>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

so from `ChatFooter` component, I get the value that is typed by the user

and finally, the question is how I can pass message value to `"/chat/:userId"` page:

```js
    export default function Chat({ messages }: any) {
      console.log(messages);
    
      return <h3>here messages</h3>;
    }
```

consider that, chat page and dashboard page is a child of this layout, so when I try to use `cloneElement(children, {messages: "hello world"})` I can't see these props, I don't know why...